# Force CMake to use absolute include path

Tags: cmake, gcov, ninja

I have a project whose directory layout looks like:

```
- src/ #Contains main source code
- ext/ #Contains external libraries and headers from GitHub
- CMakeLists.txt
```

The problem is that no matter what I do, CMake always seems to pass `ext/` to the compiler as a relative path, like this:

```
/usr/bin/c++ -I../ext mysrc.cpp
```

I've tried doing both:

```
include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/ext")
include_directories("/home/user/project/ext")
```

But it doesn't seem to matter. The directory is always passed to `-I` as `../ext`.

Why does this matter? At the end of my build I invoke `gcov -r <source file>` which tells gcov to generate coverage reports from my source file and any relative paths found within. As a result, gcov is going into `ext/` and generating reports for tons of stuff I don't care about and it's taking up a lot of time. If CMake would instead pass in `-I/home/user/project/ext` then `gcov -r` would ignore everything in `ext/`.

As far as I can tell from:
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/include_directories.html ... this isn't possible, but maybe I'm just missing something?

Edit: This appears to be a problem with specifically the `ninja` generator. When using the `Unix Makefiles` generator, *everything* is passed via absolute paths.

https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/18666

Edit2:

```
user@antimony:~/cmake_test$ ls
CMakeLists.txt  ext  src
user@antimony:~/cmake_test$ cat CMakeLists.txt 
project(Hello)

add_subdirectory(src)
user@antimony:~/cmake_test$ cat src/CMakeLists.txt 
include_directories(
    .
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/ext
)

add_executable(hello_world hello.cpp)
user@antimony:~/cmake_test$ cat src/hello.cpp 
#include <useless.h>

int main()
{
    hello h;
    return 0;
}
user@antimony:~/cmake_test$ cat ext/useless.h 
struct hello {
    int x;
};
user@antimony:~/cmake_test$ ~/Downloads/cmake-3.13.1-Linux-x86_64/bin/cmake --version
cmake version 3.13.1

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
user@antimony:~/cmake_test$ mkdir build && cd build
user@antimony:~/cmake_test/build$ ~/Downloads/cmake-3.13.1-Linux-x86_64/bin/cmake .. -G Ninja
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
...
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/cmake_test/build
user@antimony:~/cmake_test/build$ ninja -v
[1/2] /usr/bin/c++   -I../src/. -I../ext  -MD -MT src/CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir/hello.o -MF src/CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir/hello.o.d -o src/CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir/hello.o -c ../src/hello.cpp
[2/2] : && /usr/bin/c++    -rdynamic src/CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir/hello.o  -o src/hello_world   && :
user@antimony:~/cmake_test/build$ cat build.ninja
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "Ninja" Generator, CMake Version 3.13

# This file contains all the build statements describing the
# compilation DAG.

...

#############################################
# Order-only phony target for hello_world

build cmake_object_order_depends_target_hello_world: phony || src/CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir
build src/CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir/hello.o: CXX_COMPILER__hello_world ../src/hello.cpp || cmake_object_order_depends_target_hello_world
  DEP_FILE = src/CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir/hello.o.d
  INCLUDES = -I../src/. -I../ext
  OBJECT_DIR = src/CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir
  OBJECT_FILE_DIR = src/CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir
  TARGET_COMPILE_PDB = src/CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir/
  TARGET_PDB = src/hello_world.pdb

# =============================================================================
# Link build statements for EXECUTABLE target hello_world
```

Comment: Well if this is a bug in the CMake ninja generator that it converts absolute paths to relative paths have you thought about using the Makefile generator instead as a temporary workaround.  Might want to report that the bug is still an issue in the version of cmake you are using.

Comment: Actually I cant reproduce this problem using cmake 3.13.  `build.ninja` is always using a absolute path for the -I directive.

Comment: I haven't tried 3.13 yet, but if that's the case I'll have the opposite problem! Basically I want paths in src/ to be relative but paths in ext to be absolute so that gcov will ignore the external source files and only calculate coverage for my relative source files

Comment: In general cmake makes all paths absolute when it generates project files.  That's why you can't move things around once the project is created. For instance if `build` and `source` are both subdirectory of `~/example` and you rename `example` to `actual` you can't use the projects in `build` anymore.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce using `3.13`. What version of ninja do you have?

Comment: I'm not finding that to be the case. With the latest versions of ninja and cmake, all include paths are relative under Ubuntu 18

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 / cmake 3.13 / ninja 1.3.4.  Running `ninja -v` shows absolute paths for the source files and for the include directories as I would expect based on the contents of the build.ninja file produced by cmake.

Comment: I guess that you must be calling cmake from within either the source directory or one of its sub-directories.  This as you know is bugged (the link is now missing in your post) and uses relative paths instead of absolute paths. Try building in a out of source location (which I've always heard was the recommended method).  At least for me it's using absolute paths.

Comment: No, I'm doing out-of-source builds like you describe. Can you update ninja to 1.8 and try again?

Comment: If the contents of the `build.ninja` is incorrect and has relative paths that is a `cmake` issue.  You'll have to post a minimal example that reproduces the issue.  Also post if possible what happens when you run `ninja -v` to demonstrate that relative paths are used on the command line. If `ninja` is converting full paths to relative paths thats a `ninja` problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184588/discussion-between-rpgillespie-and-fred).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example shows what may be considered an in-source build. That is when the build directory is the same or a sub-directory of the src folder (not that there is a hard definition or anything, but this does trigger the ninja issue of using relative paths on the command line). Try `mkdir ~/cmake_build && cd ~/cmake_build && cmake ~/cmake_test` then it should use absolute paths for everything.

Either way there really isn't a specific way to force one or the other.  In general cmake generators will use absolute paths for everything that ends up used on the command line.  There seems to be issues with Ninja that prevent the generator from using absolute paths for in-source builds (https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/issues/1251).

Comment: I don't consider that an in-source build, but I do consider your suggestion to be an out-of-project build, so maybe that's where the difference lies. Either way I don't *want* absolute include paths for everything - I want absolute include paths for code I don't want analyzed for coverage and relative paths for everything else. Seems like a limitation of CMake so I raised an issue. Thanks for your input

Comment: In the case of Ninja I think they say in-source tree.   As for cmake here is a relevant link on why it works the way it does. https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/FAQ#why-does-cmake-use-full-paths-or-can-i-copy-my-build-tree

Comment: It's not in-source though because my source directories do not contain any build artifacts after the build is complete. In-source build means your source directories will contain `.o` files for example after you run the build afaik

Comment: Every time I've heard the phrase in-source and out-of-source builds is in reference to the directory tree.  So any build folder that is a sub-directory of the root of the source be part of the source directory tree.  But its just a general concept.  The Ninja issue was in regards to a build folder that is within the sub-directory structure of the source root.  Which we can see with this particular example.  Either way cmake doesn't work the way you want.  Why don't you try using `gcov -s` and just start excluding everything you don't want?

Comment: Can you give a sample `gcov -s` statement that excludes `ext/` and `/usr/include` headers?  It seems like `-s` cannot be used the way you describe. `-s` is for simply making the filenames look prettier by trimming `/some/long/path/leading/up/to/source.h` -> `source.h`. AFAIK, `-r` is the only way for gcov to do pre-emptive filtering of files to process

Comment: I didn't read the manual that way about the `-s` option.  But I tried it out and you are right. Might want to try `gcovr` instead and try the exclude options (along with jobs option) instead.  Maybe it'll run faster than `gcov`.

Comment: Unfortunately `gcovr` is a simply a wrapper for `gcov` so it can only be slower (besides the parallelization - but I'm already launching multiple gcov processes). I appreciate your suggestions though. Looks like either `cmake` or `gcov` is going to need a feature enhancement to get the speedup I'm looking for